# What is the interaction of the rsync --size-only and --sparse options?

Tags: rsync, sparse-files

If I use `rsync` with the `--size-only` and `--sparse` options together, if a file already exists at the destination as a full file (otherwise the same) it's not overwritten.

If I omit the `--size-only` option, the non-sparse file is overwritten with the sparse version. I *do* want the file to be overwritten and I want to keep the `--size-only` option (unless I can be convinced that I don't).

This is part of a script that gets run periodically. In the past, the `--sparse` option was not used and a lot of space has been wasted.

How can I continue to use `--space-only` (and other options I haven't included here) and have the large files overwritten as the script does its work? A search-and-destroy mission would be too "expensive".

I have tested this with `rsync` 3 in Ubuntu with ext3 and CentOS with ext4. The actual `rsync` is performed over an `ssh` connection.

Note that in the following demonstration nothing changes about the source or destination files (size, times or contents) between runs of `rsync`.

Demonstration:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse.out bs=1 seek=1M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte (1 B) copied, 0.000307332 s, 3.3 kB/s

$ stat sparse.out
  File: `sparse.out'
  Size: 1048577         Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 2377326     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  dennis)   Gid: ( 1000/  dennis)
Access: 2011-07-28 22:06:52.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2011-07-28 22:06:52.000000000 -0500
Change: 2011-07-28 22:06:52.000000000 -0500

$ du -h sparse.out
8.0K    sparse.out

$ rsync --size-only sparse.out sparse.out.rsync

$ stat sparse.out.rsync
  File: `sparse.out.rsync'
  Size: 1048577         Blocks: 2064       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 2377329     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  dennis)   Gid: ( 1000/  dennis)
Access: 2011-07-28 22:09:19.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2011-07-28 22:09:20.000000000 -0500
Change: 2011-07-28 22:09:20.000000000 -0500

$ du -h sparse.out.rsync
1.1M    sparse.out.rsync

$ rsync --size-only --sparse sparse.out sparse.out.rsync

$ stat sparse.out.rsync
  File: `sparse.out.rsync'
  Size: 1048577         Blocks: 2064       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 2377329     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  dennis)   Gid: ( 1000/  dennis)
Access: 2011-07-28 22:09:19.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2011-07-28 22:09:20.000000000 -0500
Change: 2011-07-28 22:09:20.000000000 -0500

$ du -h sparse.out.rsync
1.1M    sparse.out.rsync

$ rsync --sparse sparse.out sparse.out.rsync

$ stat sparse.out.rsync
  File: `sparse.out.rsync'
  Size: 1048577         Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 2377330     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  dennis)   Gid: ( 1000/  dennis)
Access: 2011-07-28 22:11:23.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2011-07-28 22:11:23.000000000 -0500
Change: 2011-07-28 22:11:23.000000000 -0500

$ du -h sparse.out.rsync
8.0K    sparse.out.rsync

$ stat -c '%b %B %o %s' sparse.out sparse.out.rsync
16 512 4096 1048577
16 512 4096 1048577

$ cmp sparse5.out sparse5.out.rsync
$
```

Comment: I suspect you'll have to relax one of your constraints. How about running a local program on the target once to sparsify files wherever possible?

Answer (score 1):

`--size-only` tells rsync to skip files which match in size. Since sparse files are preallocated they can be the same size while having different content. I would suggest that you remove the `--size-only` option and make sure that modification times are synced (`--times`). rsync then won't check the contents of the file if the modification times match (which is what I assume you are trying to avoid wtih `--size-only`), while still syncing files which have been modified.